# If I fill my harddrive, why can't I log in?

Tags: login, lightdm, disk-usage

I was stupid, I kept ignoring the warnings that my harddrive space was running low and left a download running in the background. When I logged out, I wasn't taken back to the login screen (LightDM), and when I rebooted I didn't get the login screen either. Instead I got a terminal-like screen that listed drivers/daemons being loaded, but didn't have a prompt. I could still access the terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-F1` (and `F2` etc).

After barking up many wrong trees I solved it by deleting a file or two. My question is, why did this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the root partition has filled (or the partition that holds `/var` to be more precise), there will not be any space to write to `/var/log/auth.log`, which usually prevents login attempts from anyone besides the `superuser`.

The same goes for `/home`. There are files in your home directory that have to be updated and if there is no space left on the device will prevent you from logging in.

Comment: It's worth noting that even though its easily explained, we still consider this to be a pretty serious bug. You shouldn't have to drop down to a VT to log in when your disk is full.

Comment: afaik it is not needed to drop down to a VT. failsafe mode should still work (though I do not have a hdd to test this on ;))  @tumbleweed

Comment: @tumbleweed is there a launchpad bug I can subscribe to?

Comment: @tumbleweed or rinzwind - by the way, do you happen to know the name of the terminal-like screen I described?

Comment: That's probably the normal boot screen where the commands are shown during booting (Ubuntu nowadays hides this but it is still there).

Comment: @d3vid: It's just called a Virtual Terminal (VT). I'm guessing it's [bug #35217](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/35217), which is a fairly ancient bug. Oh, and hi to another Capetonian :)

Comment: @Rinzwind: Failsafe doesn't work. I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Either `/tmp` filled up so it couldn't create `.X11-unix` or `/home` filled up so it couldn't create `.Xauthority`. Either way, graphical login would be nonfunctional.

Modern Ubuntu defaults to a RAM-backed `/tmp`; however I recall in 2012 this was not the case.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/645175)

Comment: The heck it doesn't answer the question. Fill up /tmp and watch the behavior I just described happen. By default /tmp is on / in ubuntu and he probably did a single partition install. On the other hand the answer about logging is dead wrong. If true, logging into a TTY wouldn't work either.

Comment: .Xauthority lives in ~ (/home/username) your answer is only accurate if /tmp is on the same partition as that. That assumes facts not in evidence. @Rinzwind answer is more precise. Yours could be. I recommend you [edit] to provide the detail that makes your answer true.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount