# How can I use RAM storage for the /tmp directory and how to set a maximum amount of RAM usage for it?

Tags: filesystem, fstab, tmpfs

After seeing [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up#comment90312_20783) by [Anonymous](https://askubuntu.com/users/29112/anonymous) on the question [How is the /tmp directory cleaned up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up), I found that it would be a great idea to implement on my system, since I have 16GB of RAM and I never used all of it.

> My temporary files never get written to the disk. They get written to a RAM disk. I did put `tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0` in /etc/fstab.

My question is:

Can I set a maximum value for RAM Usage for `/tmp`? And in that case, what would happen if the maximum amount got exceeded, would it write into the hard-disk drive?

I have read a solution which states:

> ```
> mkdir -p /tmp/ram
> sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=512M tmpfs /tmp/ram/
> ```

But in my understanding, this won't be a permanent solution. If I need it to be permanent, it has to be added to the `/etc/fstab` configuration file.

If this is the correct solution, how can I transform that mount command into a line in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: this is also a good idea if you have and SSD as you will not 'consume' it with not useful writings ...

Comment: Ha ha exactly the same question brought me here :D

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You are absolutely right. The according fstab entry would look like this:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=512M 0 0
```

**Please note:**

As `tmpfs` gets filled up, it will behave as any physical hard drive by giving an "not enough space" error. While rebooting (and thus emptying the cache) will fix this, you may run into trouble when a single operation consumes more space to begin with than there's space on `tmpfs`. In this case your computer will start to swap from ram to disk, which will make your system crawl to a halt, given you've got a swap partition to begin with, of course.

Considering this, a size of 512MB might be far too less nowadays, since much more ram is in existence in modern machines and it has become much cheaper. Since you've already got 16GB of ram, using the default value of half your ram for `tmpfs` should more than suffice for almost all scenarios. To use the default value, simply leave out the `size=512M` entry in your `/etc/fstab` file.

**Another note:**

You can quite as easily mount other system folders into ramdisk as well, such as

`/var/cache`

`/var/games`

`/var/log/apt` (use only `defaults,noatime` without `mode=` or `nosuid`)

**But beware:** the same rules apply as above, running out of space might cause major trouble. E.g. imagine running out of space for /var/log/apt will render you unable to install any programs!
Furthermore, loading `/var/log` folders into ramdisk will delete all your log files upon reboot, so you won't be able to debug your system if anything unexpected happens.
So use these settings at your own risk!

**Editorial note:**
I removed the `/run` in `tmpfs` mount option since this folder and its subfolders are already mounted in `tmpfs` by default.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, /var/tmp/ is for keeping files after reboot. Thats the main difference between this and /tmp/ , so YOU should not move /var/tmp to ram.

Comment: I checked that and you seem to be right. I scratched it from the answer. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: I'd add the `nodev` option also.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I added security related mount options nosuid, nodev and noexec.

Comment: If Ubuntu runs out of 4GB tmpfs, will it use my 20GB SWAP partition?

Comment: Yes, I'll need to add this, too. As soon as tmpfs exeeeds its limits, it'll extend to swap partition (give there is one).

Comment: Does allocating half your RAM to this mean that half your RAM is reserved for the RAMDISK, or is it only a cap to what the RAMDISK may consume, and whatever is not in use is free RAM that gets assigned to whatever program needs RAM??

Comment: @matt It's only a cap.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.. although, there'd be no automated warning in case the RAMDISK is becoming too full until it's too late, would there?

Comment: Even when your ram is depleted, it will replenish itself after a while. Your system will seem to crawl to a halt but it will recover with time. I wouldn't even bother to reboot since that might take even longer than to wait for the system to free up enough ram to run smoothly again.

Comment: You can use "fatrace" to see how much tmp activity there really is, and if this is worth it.

Comment: adding `noexec` caused my [netbeans 8.1 installation to fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694188/unable-to-install-netbeans-8-1). I take it by default /tmp does allow exec right?

Comment: Yes, it is mounted exec by default. Mounting it noexec is considered to be an additional layer of security, but it is also known to break some things from time to time.

Comment: When you put a /tmp line in /etc/fstab, the systemd-fstab-generator will end up creating /run/systemd/generator/tmp.mount , which you can then look at directly to see what's happening under the hood  (and i.e. to compare against the version that Ubuntu ships in /usr/share/systemd).

Comment: Q: why add the ```defaults``` option? If it's omitted, I'd assume that...the ```default``` options are being used anyway?

Comment: @ckujau: In fact, the `default` option is completely unnecessary in this case. It's usually used as a placeholder for cases in which this field would be empty otherwise. I'm keeping it around in case I'd remove all other  options. Only then would it be needed.

Comment: Could you add information on why `nosuid` should be used?

Comment: If I'm not mistake, which I usually am, the system resorting to swap should have the same impact on performance as using the disk for `/tmp` to begin with since both scenarios depend on disk speed. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Dan yeah, that's my point. you cannot (in this specific context) go wrong with delegating memory for tmp

Answer (score 59):

On systems using `systemd`, you have the option of using a systemd unit file instead of fstab to accomplish the goal of using `tmpfs` to mount `tmp`. On my Ubuntu 16.04 system, I ran:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount
sudo systemctl enable tmp.mount
sudo systemctl start tmp.mount
```

The file `/usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount` looks like:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
[Unit]
Description=Temporary Directory
Documentation=man:hier(7)
Documentation=http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=!/tmp
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target umount.target
After=swap.target

[Mount]
What=tmpfs
Where=/tmp
Type=tmpfs
Options=mode=1777,strictatime

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

Using FuzzyQ's fstab approach, systemd translates your fstab entries into mount units dynamically. I don't think either approach is better.

In order to set the maximum limit for the RAM as asked, one would need to add `size=512M` to the `Options` line, separated by a comma.

Comment: You will need `systemctl enable tmp.mount` after cp else systemctl will fail with message "`Failed to start tmp.mount: Unit tmp.mount not found.`"

Comment: @Rick, it's even better to use `systemctl edit tmp.mount` that would be distro-neutral. That puts your changes into override.conf so that you don't alter default tmp.mount and you could delete override.conf easily to go back to default configuration.

Comment: Ditto what Bulat said about using systemctl edit, and also use `ln -s` rather than `cp` in the first step.