# How to make ubuntu use more RAM to cache a specific set of binaries?

Tags: ram, cache, preload

After 2 weeks of trying, failing, trying again, still failing, I finally got Ubuntu stable and operational.

My hard disk is quite old and slow but I have excessive RAM (16 GB 2133 mhz), so I was thinking about using that RAM for faster fetching.

**How can I *manually* cache programs' binaries before running it?** I know about preload but that's not what I want, I want to be able to lock the process' binaries in the memory so it can't get out and I wanna do that manually, preferably with GUI but I don't have a problem with terminal.

I don't wanna run it, just load the binaries and dependencies in memory.

Do you know anything that can do that?

Answer (score 5):

There is a rather lengthy tutorial on the forums you might like:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1594694

> The guide basically explains how to create a squashfs image out of your existing Ubuntu installation and copy the entire image to RAM upon boot to speed up your OS. I will also go into some detail of how to make your /home mount from a regular hard drive thereby making sure the important information one would wish to save on their machine would remain untouched between boots.

See the guide for details.

Comment: This is as close as it gets to what i want i think.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Three keywords to google and some helpful links:

Change swappiness:
[How do I configure swappiness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness)

/tmp to RAM ():
[How can I use RAM storage for the /tmp directory and how to set a maximum amount of RAM usage for it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount)

Disable access time:
http://intensecogitation.info/2010/06/15/optimizing-ubuntu-debians-file-system-by-disabling-access-time/

These there were also lately covered in Hak5 for laptop battery optimization but these tricks should be also useful for your as the way to save power is to use less of that good old hard disk:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XloTXFgNL7s