# Computer shutting down 5 minutes after starting a game

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown

So after I start any game (for example Starbound or FEZ) on my Xubuntu installation, after 5 minutes my computer just shuts down without even displaying a warning.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how it could be fixed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you check you CPU temperature? Install lm-sensors and type sensors in the terminal while the game is running.

Comment: see the shutdown log file http://askubuntu.com/questions/58625/where-is-the-shutdown-log

Comment: This looks very familiar to me. I guess your GPU is generating to much heat. Your system goes down preventing damage to your hardware.

Comment: I had a problem like that and I solved it from ram optimization. My computer used to much ram memory, check it for your problem ;)

Comment: I'll check it out. Could you link me to a guide on how to optimize RAM?

Comment: A search here on "RAM Optimize" lead to http://askubuntu.com/questions/258753/how-to-make-ubuntu-use-more-ram/258766#258766

Comment: What kind of computer do you have? I had similar problem with a dual graphics Intel-AMD laptop. I am not a gamer, so I reduced the speed of the card... See http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395

Comment: @Rmano I have an Acer Aspire V3-571G, [see here](http://www.acer.de/ac/de/DE/content/model/NX.M7EEG.003)

Comment: Seems a NVIDIA chipset, so different from mine. But the symptoms are of overheating. Are you using open or proprietary drivers? Maybe there is some switch to throttle down the graphic card somewhere. Add the fact that the graphic card is an Nvidia one and try to see if some expert comes out...