# Unable to Install Netbeans 8.1

Tags: 14.04, netbeans

I am running the 64bit version of Ubuntu 14.04 desktop and when I run [the netbeans installer](https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=php&bits=x64) (PHP version) I get the following error message:

```
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Preparing bundled JVM ...
netbeans-8.1-php-linux-x64.sh: 1: eval: /tmp/.nbi-4114443.tmp/jre-8u60-linux-x64.bin: Permission denied
Cannot prepare bundled JVM to run the installer.
Most probably the bundled JVM is not compatible with the current platform.
See FAQ at http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUnableToPrepareBundledJdk for more information.
```

When I checked the wiki, it tells me:

```
On Debian-based 64bit distributions (such as Ubuntu) it is usually enough to install the ia32-libs package to successfully start the bundled 32bit installer.
```

When I try running

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I get the error:

```
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

So then I run

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

... and then I execute the installer and get the same darn error message:

```
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Preparing bundled JVM ...
netbeans-8.1-php-linux-x64.sh: 1: eval: /tmp/.nbi-4114845.tmp/jre-8u60-linux-x64.bin: Permission denied
Cannot prepare bundled JVM to run the installer.
Most probably the bundled JVM is not compatible with the current platform.
See FAQ at http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUnableToPrepareBundledJdk for more information.
```

**What do I need to do in order to install netbeans 8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)?**

#### System State

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux stuart-home 3.19.0-31-generic #36~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 10:21:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of java -version

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

---

### Update 07-11-2015

Ive since tried [installing Java 9](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html) but that didn't work either.

---

### Update 08-11-2015

**As a workaround,** it appears that the [full netbeans download](http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.1/final/bundles/netbeans-8.1-linux.sh) works. This type of netbeans installation only has one download option rather than 1 for x86 and 1 for x64. I wonder if it is related to that or just the PHP version has a bug?

[image]

For now, I'm going to leave it at that and use the full version, but I would be keen to see if there is an actual solution for those of us who just want the minimal PHP installation.

Comment: how you are trying to install? did you try `sudo bash netbeansSetup.sh` ?

Comment: before installing did you install latest JRE( Java Runtime Environment)? by this `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre` ? [ref](http://openjdk.java.net/install/)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I tried installing with `sudo sh netbeans-8.1-php-linux-x64.sh` because the first line in the file is `#!/bin/sh` and not `#!/bin/bash`. Also I don't have the openjdk installed, instead I have the webupd8 ppa for java 9 installed (after trying with 8 which also failed).  I provided a link to how these java versions were installed.

Comment: you must first install openjdk

Comment: @edwardtorvalds turns out that's not it either. I ran `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` and I got the message `openjdk-7-jdk is already the newest version.
openjdk-7-jdk set to manually installed.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem (NetBeans 8.1, Debian 8.1).

In /etc/fstab I removed "**noexec**" parameter in **/tmp** definition, remount /tmp and now it works.  (*missing execution permission*) ;)

Comment: Great that worked. I had noexec in my fstab because I used [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount) to mount /tmp in RAM. I'm guessing you did something similar?

Comment: Yes, I did the same.

Answer (score 0):

You must have downloaded netbeans from their site which, is a tar file.

- extract to a folder of your choice.
- Make sure you have JDK installed.
- Open terminal and change to directory containing file netbeans.sh.
- Then execute the shell script file using command:

  `./netbeans.sh`
- This needs to be done with elevated permissions.

Then a window appears for installing netbeans in GUI form.

Comment: The file (called `netbeans-8.1-php-linux-x64.sh` is not a tar file (I looked inside with vim). I have already tried executing it with `sudo sh netbeans.sh` which is when I get the error messages shown in my question.

Comment: Just run that .sh file by running the following command in terminal:
sudo ./(filename)

Comment: yep that didnt work for me. Same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to install netbeans for a non root user on my computer but addin owner execute bit helped. The command used is this:

```
chmod u+x netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
```

After that, when I run

```
./netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
```

It worked,the installation run without any problem after that..