# Any way to prevent wallch to update .cache/wallpaper?

Tags: ssd, desktop-background, wallch

Directing Wallch to My Pictures and rotate every X mn, I want to preserve my SSD from this directory to be constantly updated along the day by files that are several Megs each. Yet I disabled Walch's thumb cache at `.cache/wallch`. I'm afraid there is no way to prevent update of `.config/wallch/History.conf`, but this one is a very little file so I hope constant update won't overwear my ssd. `.cache/wallpaper` is the remaining question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a [**temporary filesystem on your RAM**](https://askubuntu.com/q/173094/783023) and then replace the offending directories with [symbolic links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link) (you might have to stop `wallch`before doing this)

```
rm ~.cache/offending-dir

ln -s /absolute/path/to/offending/dir /tmp
```

Comment: I already have zram-config installed, eating half my 8Gigs RAM. I read that leaving default for tmpfs will eat the other half and 512 is not enough. What is the tradeoff ?

Comment: @useful, what is your usecase currently for zram ? The downside of using `tmp` on your RAM is that you can run out of space, i.e. if you define 512MB and try to compress a file with ZIP (which usually uses `/tmp/`for temp files) that is larger than 512MB, it won't work. Depending on what you do, I think 1GB of `/tmp`should be enough, but you will find that out quickly if you test it.

Comment: Thank you Robert. In the lap time I also discovered that Wallch (4.0, not daily 4.187) 4.183 allows to disable history (Edit menu), and when we choose preferences to display Wallpapers in Paths style, the thumbs cache is no more updated :-) and can be deleted. Nice when we have a huge number frequently changing for those concerned like I was with their SSD health. I just removed zram for swap (I have a 16G partition that remains unused most of the time ) and I'm now using a 2GB tmpfs. I think I'll use it for FF cache too. Bye