# How to execute a bash script before shutdown using systemd?

Tags: command-line, bash, shutdown, systemd

I have a executable bash script (.bash_history_cleaner) which cleans my bash history

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit
```

I want to execute this script on system shutdown or restart and followed [this answer which uses systemd](https://askubuntu.com/a/795406/158636) with service name as `bash_history_cleaner.service` and enabled it in systemctl. The service is up and running,

```
[Unit]
Description=Bash History Cleaner

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/eka/Scripts/.bash_history_cleaner

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Its intended behaviour should be to clean my bash history when either shutdown or restart. But its not working, I shutdown and restared the system many times but the script is not executed. How do we execute a bash script before shutdown using systemd?

Comment: What's the goal of `cat /dev/null >` vs `echo "" >`?  Does the script work when you run it directly, ie: `bash /home/eka/Scripts/.bash_history_cleaner`?

Comment: Are you implementing this as a *system* systemd unit? if so, `~/` is not going to resolve to your *user's* home directory

Comment: @steeldriver you are correct it was not resolving I had to give the full path

Comment: @earthmeLon you can even skip `cat` altogether and have it just like so `> /path/to/file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not take advantage of the Linux system and it's `/tmp` directory to store your `.bash_history` in a more volatile place?

To change the location of your `.bash_history` file, you need to set the `HISTFILE` variable.  To have the file deleted every reboot, place the file in the `/tmp/` directory.

You can add something such as the following to your `~/.bashrc` file so that these settings persist:

```bsh
HISTFILE=/tmp/.bash_history
```

You can confirm other users cannot read your history by checking out the file permissions of the history file created:

```bsh
ls -lsa /tmp/.bash_history
```

This will cause your user's history to be removed upon reboot, but will not affect others.  You can set this system level configuration files such as `/etc/bash.bashrc` if you really want.  You can even [put `/tmp` into RAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount) to ensure it gets cleared.

Comment: Your answer is a good solution for his problem, but unfortunately it does notanswer the question in that I am also interested in to know: How to run a systems command on shutdown?